# JMeter examples with scripts

Tags: jmeter

I am going to write the first JMeter application to test the new mobile apps and desktop web application.
I see the tutorials on `tutorialpoints.com`. I want the more advanced examples, e.g. user go to the website and then click some buttons and save to db and refresh the page.
Capture all these events and I believe I need to write some scripts.
Is there any examples that I can reference??

Comment: Check https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2546/where-can-i-find-good-jmeter-tutorials

Answer (score 3):

The only good "examples" I can think of you should already have given you obtained JMeter by [downloading](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) and unpacking the bundle.

The examples are available via `File -> Templates` entry of the JMeter Main Menu:

[image: JMeter Templates]

Also you can find the corresponding .jmx scripts under `bin/templates` folder of your JMeter installation. Check out [How to Save ‘Loads’ of Time Using JMeter's Template Feature](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature) article for more information on how to use existing and create new templates.

You can also try looking for examples i.e. on Github like [this](https://github.com/betweenbrain/Joomla-JMeter-Tests) or [this one](https://github.com/betweenbrain/Joomla-JMeter-Tests), but they are not guaranteed to work.